# if [ `ls $op_file` ]; then is returning true even the file is not found

Tags: shell

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the o/p file name"
read op_file
echo "Enter the count"
read count

echo "OP filename : "
echo $op_file
if [ `ls $op_file` ]; then
 echo "O/P file found"
else
exit 0
fi
```

I'm trying to check whether the filename is existing or not.Have to proceed if the file is existing. Though the above code doesn't give me error. It prints O/P file found even though the file is not found by ls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script can be refactored to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter the o/p file name" op_file
read -p "Enter the count" count
echo "OP filename: $op_file"

if [ -f "$op_file" ]; then
  echo "O/P file found"
else
   exit 1
fi
```

Better to use `-f "$file"` check for checking existence of a file. Also see `man test`

Answer (score 1):

Use the -e operator in your if, this checks the for existence of a file, so:

```
if [ -e $op_file ]; then
  echo "O/P file found"
else
  exit 0
fi
```